# Logstash Combine multiple json array into one

Tags: arrays, ruby, json, logstash

I have the below output from Logstash.

```
"product" => [
        [ 0] "1234",
        [ 1] "3345",
]
 "quantity" => [
        [ 0] "12",
        [ 1] "12",
]
```

This is parsed output from an XML. Can i combine these two arrays to a single array? Something like this: (Not sure if the below is the correct format)

```
"ProductDetails"  => [
     [0] => [
       "product" : "1234"
        "quantity" : "12"
]
]
```

I want to combine like this so that it can be easier for me to retrieve. I think this can be done using ruby.. But i have very little experience in that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
▶ hash = { product: [1, 2], quantity: [:a, :b] }
▶ hash.values.reduce(&:zip).map { |a| hash.keys.zip a }.map &:to_h
#⇒  [
#  [0] {
#    :product => 1,
#    :quantity => :a
#  },
#  [1] {
#    :product => 2,
#    :quantity => :b
#  }
# ]
```